# Groupby with Where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table `PropertyViewer`. I need to `Groupby 'ip_address'` only Where `'property id'` is same. How should I do it in MYSQL?

Comment: What do you mean by `Where 'property id' is same`?

Comment: You will have to explain a little better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `PropertyViewer`
GROUP BY `ip_address`, `property_id`;
```

You can change the ordering in

```
`ip_address`, `property_id`
```

in any way that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need:

```
SELECT *
  FROM PropertyViewer
 GROUP BY property_id, ip_address;
```

This groups items with the same `property_id` and `ip_address` together.